# Bootstrap´s 4 PlaceHolder on Select Angular 4

Tags: html, angular, bootstrap-4

i made a Select with dynamic values using ngModel directive and the Bootstrap Framework, it works. My problem is that i want to add a placeholder, but the ng directive seems to ruining it.

Here is what i have:

```
   <select [(ngModel)]="usuario.pais" name="s" class="form-control">
     <option value="">Select a Country</option><!--My PlaceHolder-->
     <option *ngFor="let pais of paises" value="pais.codigo">{{pais.nombre}}</option>
   </select>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Which directive is not working?! I think the value here should be in brackets: `<option *ngFor="let pais of paises" [value]="pais.codigo">`...

Comment: And I think there is no select in bootstrap, there is a dropdown: `https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/dropdown/examples`

Comment: The <option>Select a Country</option> should work as placeholder, and instead of showing it, it appears to being blank. Directives and values work perfect

Comment: And: is your select part of a `form` or `ngForm`? And did you include `import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';`

Comment: Then, does the object referenced by `pais` in `usuario.pais` match the `[value]="pais.codigo"`

Comment: a form. And yes, i had import the FormsModule

Comment: All the Select works perfect, but the option "select country" appears blank

Comment: According to the bootstrap official documentation, you can use `selected` attribute: `<option selected>Select a Country</option>`. See https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#select-menu

Comment: @KKK that is bootstrap without angular...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe try this:
In TS:

```
public usuario = {pais: ''};

public paises = [{nombre: 'la France', codigo: 'fr'}, {nombre: 'deutscheland', codigo: 'de'}];
```

in HTML:

```
<select [(ngModel)]="usuario.pais" name="s" class="form-control">
  <option value="">Select a Country</option>
  <option *ngFor="let pais of paises" [value]="pais.codigo">
    {{pais.nombre}}
  </option>
</select>
```

Comment: If i try this out in stackblitz, it works - showing `Select a Country` initially...

Comment: I assume your `pais` inside `usuario` is not of type string? (like the type of `codigo`)

Comment: Works perfect! Thanks

Comment: Glad to help out. I know the pain with selects! :)